# How do we view a JSP page i IBM Websphere portal as an IFrame

Tags: websphere-portal

How do we view a JSP page i IBM Websphere portal as an IFrame. I have done this before but i cant remember which portlet i used. can some one help with regards to resolving this issue

Answer (score 0):

Which websphere portal version? And do you mean the JSP Server portlet?

Comment: WebSphere portal V8.0.0.1, Though i manage to download Web Portlet from green house, its not working for external links

Answer (score 0):

There is always the Web Clipper Portlet in iframe mode:

http://infolib.lotus.com/resources/portal/8.0.0/doc/en_us/PT800ACD001/admin/adclclpr.html

-ScottH